# How to pass a value (which i got from ui-router) to a modal/view through state.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, jhipster

My state. js is like this

```
 .state('lab.new-equip', {
            parent: 'lab',
            url: '/{labId}/new-equipment',
            data: {
                authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
            },
            onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
                $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'app/entities/lab/lab-equipments-dialog.html',
                    controller: 'LabEquipmentsDialogController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        entity: function () {
                            return {
                                roomId: $stateParams.labId,
                                equipementName: null,
                                specification: null,
                                manufacturer: null,
                                quantity: null,
                                author: null,
                                id: null
                            }.$promise;
                        }
                    }
                }).result.then(function () {
                    $state.go('lab', null, {reload: true});
                }, function () {
                    $state.go('lab');
                });
            }]
        })
```

I have got the value of the labId using ui-router as below

```
  ui-sref="lab.new-equip({labId:vm.lab.labId})"
```

Now I am trying to pass this labId to the view as the value of roomId. Hence i have tried sending with the help of **$stateParams**. 

But i couldn't get the value populated in my modal.
 If i change that roomId to an Integer like 2 or 3, it is populating in the modal. But not the previous way.

How can i achieve this?

Is there any other way to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code:

```
function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/entities/lab/lab-equipments-dialog.html',
            backdrop: 'static',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                selectedRow: function () {                    
                    return row.entity.labId;
                }
            },
            controller: function ($scope, $uibModal, selectedRow) {
                $scope.selectedRow = selectedRow;
                $stateParams.labId = $scope.labId;
            }
        }).result.then(function () {
            $state.go('lab', null, {reload: true});
        }, function () {
            $state.go('lab');
        });
```

Comment: If i change the controller as you told, where can i declare the corresponding controller 'LabDialogController'?

Comment: Bind it in the `app/entities/lab/lab-equipments-dialog.html`

Answer (score 0):

Just add like the following

```
resolve: {
                    entity: function () {
                        return {
                            roomId: null,
                            equipementName: null,
                            specification: null,
                            manufacturer: null,
                            quantity: null,
                            author: null,
                            id: null
                        }.$promise;
                    }
                    roomId: function (){
                    return $stateParams.id;
                    }
```

and inject the roomId in the controller to use it in your html page.